B1SLayer Get with Params
I´m using B1SLayer for SAP B1 Nugget in C#, I need to use some GET service with JSON content like below but I can't find the way to do it. I'm expecting someone can tell my the way to do it.

            var serviceLayer = new SLConnection(uriOrigenSl, NombreBaseDatos, usuarioSAP, passwordSAP);
            await serviceLayer.LoginAsync();

            EscribeLog("OK[getProjectsByOwner]: Pasa login");
            SubprojectSL resposeSL = new SubprojectSL();
            // Enviar la solicitud POST para crear la nota de entrega
            resposeSL = await serviceLayer.Request("ProjectManagementService_GetSubproject")
                .GetAsync<SubprojectSL>();

            EscribeLog("OK[getProjectsByOwner]: Respuesta: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resposeSL));
            ro.Data = resposeSL;
            await serviceLayer.LogoutAsync();


I had find the solution, the correct way to do it is making a Body and send the request using PostAsync(Body)
            var Body = new
            {
                PM_SubprojectDocumentParams = new
                {
                    AbsEntry = idAbs
                }
            };

            // EscribeLog(uriOrigenSl + "," + NombreBaseDatos + "," + usuarioSAP + "," + passwordSAP + "JSON: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ordenVenta));
            //Conexion SL 
            var serviceLayer = new SLConnection(uriOrigenSl, NombreBaseDatos, usuarioSAP, passwordSAP);
            await serviceLayer.LoginAsync();

            EscribeLog("OK[getProjectsByOwner]: Pasa login");
            SubprojectSL resposeSL = new SubprojectSL();
            // Enviar la solicitud POST para crear la nota de entrega
            resposeSL = await serviceLayer.Request("ProjectManagementService_GetSubproject")
                .PostAsync<SubprojectSL>(Body);

            EscribeLog("OK[getProjectsByOwner]: Respuesta: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resposeSL));
            ro.Data = resposeSL;


mark your asnwer as solution
